# How do I properly end the 'fg' command of the instance?

Tags: zope

I keep running into this issue when I need to temporarily end a Zope server in order to do something. If I run the script

./bin/zopectrl fg
or
./bin/isntance fg

It launches zope's server gets the ports it needs and starts serving. The only way I found to end this command is to do ctrl-z and then disown %1 however once I start it up, the resources it took the first time are blocked from being used again. THe only way I know to fix this is to restart the whole server which is not efficient.

How to I stop the script properly so I can start it up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about CTRL-Z and then kill %1 to stop the process thus returning the resources it consummed for reuse?

Comment: I didn't know I could do that! Wow. What if I incidentally did disown can I somehow close the process without rebooting the machine?